# How does podman behave when using sudo vs not using sudo

Tags: podman, rhel8

I'm running podman 2.0.5 on RHEL8 and I'm puzzled by how it works when invoking a command by using sudo vs not using sudo.  Especially confusing is when I ran port mapping and trying to expose a port through the host.  Using `sudo podman run -p 8080:8080 <pod-name>` I was able to curl through localhost:8080 but trying the ip:8080 wouldn't work.  If I dropped `sudo` from the command it mapped the port as expected and I could connect from the outside through the ip address.  You would think that using `sudo` would allow greater connectivity not the other way around.

Also, I am confused by using `sudo` to build images vs not using `sudo`.  When you build with sudo it goes to one registry and when you don't it goes to another registry.  I see blogs/articles about using podman with root/rootless commands but I don't really understand how (or why) things are going to different places, or have different visibility to the user based on using `sudo`.

If I elevate to root using `sudo su` and try to run podman, the (podman) command isn't recognized at all ('command not found').  Can someone explain a bit what is going on here? Is this a feature or a bug?

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` runs the command with root privileges, so `sudo podman` will access the user's local container storage directory.

When you elevate into a shell you basically logged in as root, and will see root's shell environment.

```
kim@vnv ~
$ sudo /bin/bash -c "echo $HOME"
/home/kim
kim@vnv ~
$ sudo /bin/bash 
[vnv kim]# echo $HOME
/root
```